# Orbeon - Proxy portlet on weblogic crashes during deployment

Tags: weblogic, orbeon, java-6, jrockit

I have been trying to setup Orbeon Forms proxy portlet on Liferay 6.1. Liferay is being hosted on weblogic 12c using jrockit 1.6. After deploying proxy-portlet.war, whole environment crashes.

I have also tried increasing memory. Did not help.

Errormessage:

```
<Apr 29, 2016 11:38:15 AM EEST> <Info> <ServletContext-/proxy-portlet> <BEA-000000> <Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext> 
[JRockit] ERROR: The JVM has crashed. Writing crash information to /opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/user_projects/domains/test-staging/jrockit.22399.dump.

===== BEGIN DUMP =============================================================
JRockit dump produced after 0 days, 00:20:59 on Fri Apr 29 11:38:15 2016

    **************************************************************************
    *  If you see this dump, please go to                                    *
    *  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/go2troubleshooting.html  *
    *  for troubleshooting information.                                      *
    **************************************************************************

Additional information is available in:
  /opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/user_projects/domains/test-staging/jrockit.22399.dump
No snapshot file (core dump) will be created because core dumps have been
disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited"
before starting JRockit again.

Error Message: Illegal memory access. [54]
Signal info  : si_signo=11, si_code=2 si_addr=0x7f58e3996f00
Version      : Oracle JRockit(R) R28.2.7-7-155314-1.6.0_45-20130329-0641-linux-x86_64
CPU          : Intel (null) (HT) SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 Intel64
Number CPUs  : 4
Tot Phys Mem : 16658980864 (15887 MB)
OS version   : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
Linux version 2.6.39-300.28.1.el6uek.x86_64 (mockbuild@ca-build44.us.oracle.com) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Feb 5 22:51:31 PST 2013 (x86_64)
Hypervisor   : Xen v4.1
Thread System: Linux NPTL
LibC release : 2.12-stable
Java locking : Lazy unlocking enabled (class banning) (transfer banning)
State        : JVM is running
Command Line : -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.Name= -Djava.security.policy=/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled=true -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile=/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/user_projects/domains/test-staging/servers/test-staging/data/nodemanager/boot.properties -Dweblogic.nodemanager.ServiceEnabled=true -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true -Dweblogic.ReverseDNSAllowed=false -Xns:256m -Xms12288m -Xmx12288m -Xverbose:opt,memory,memdbg -Xverboselog:verbose.log -Xgc:throughput -XX:+UseCallProfiling -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8889 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dspring.profiles.active=test,staging -DUseSunHttpHandler=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/endorsed:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/endorsed -da -Dplatform.home=/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver -Dwls.home=/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.management.discover=false -Dweblogic.management.server=-Dwlw.iterativeDev=false -Dwlw.testConsole=false -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole=false -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath -Dsun.java.command=weblogic.Server -Dsun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD weblogic.Server
Repository   : /tmp/2016_04_29_11_17_17_22399
java.home    : /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre
j.class.path : /opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/opt/oracle/jrockit/lib/tools.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_12.1.1.0.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/xqrl.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/opt/oracle/jrockit/lib/tools.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_12.1.1.0.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/webservices.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar::/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/utils/config/10.3/config-launch.jar::/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbynet.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/common/derby/lib/derbytools.jar::
j.lib.path   : /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/jrockit:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/../lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/native:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/jrockit:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/../lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/native:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8
JAVA_HOME    : /opt/oracle/jrockit
_JAVA_OPTIONS: <not set>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/jrockit:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/../lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/native:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/jrockit:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/../lib/amd64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/patch_wls1211/profiles/default/native:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64:/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/oci920_8
LD_ASSUME_KERNEL: <not set>
LD_PRELOAD   : <not set>
StackOverFlow: 0 StackOverFlowErrors have occured
OutOfMemory  : 0 OutOfMemoryErrors have occured
C Heap       : Good; no memory allocations have failed
GC Strategy  : Mode: throughput, with strategy: genparpar (basic strategy: genparpar)
GC Status    : OC is not running. Last finished OC was OC#0.
             : YC is not running. Last finished YC was YC#42.
YC Promotion : Last YC successfully promoted all objects
YC History   : Ran 42 YCs since last OC.
Heap         : 0x100000000 - 0x400000000  (Size: 12288 MB)
Compaction   : (no compaction area)
Allocation   : TLA-min: 2048, TLA-preferred: 32768 TLA-waste limit: 2048
NurseryList  : 0x100000000 - 0x110000000
KeepArea     : 0x10bffffd0 - 0x110000000
KA Markers   : [ 0x107ffffe0,  0x10bffffd0 , 0x110000000 ]
Forbidden A  : (none)
Previous KA  : 0x107ffffe0 - 0x10bffffd0
Previous FA  : (none)
CompRefs     : References are compressed, with heap base 0x0 and shift 3.

Registers (from ThreadContext: 0x7f5959ae16c0:
  rax = 00007f59db77aa10   rcx = 00000000fedb9a20 
  rdx = 0000000101873840   rbx = 00000001018737b0 
  rsp = 00007f5959ae1b18   rbp = 0000000100721340 
  rsi = 0000000101862140   rdi = 00000001018737b0 
   r8 = 0000000000000005    r9 = 00000000fed50c10 
  r10 = 00007f58da942b98   r11 = 0000000000000090 
  r12 = 0000000000000000   r13 = 0000000000000018 
  r14 = 00000001018737c0   r15 = 0000000000000000 
   cs = 000000000000e033    fs = 0000001500000000 
   gs = 0015000000000000 
  rip = 00007f58e3996f00 flags = 0000000000000202 

Loaded modules:
(* denotes the module where the exception occured)
0000000000400000-00000000004128c3  /opt/oracle/jrockit/bin/java
00007fffb57ff000-00007fffb57ffa7c  /opt/oracle/jrockit/bin/java
0000003b01c00000-0000003b01c01fef  /lib64/libdl.so.2
0000003b02000000-0000003b02016ed3  /lib64/libpthread.so.0
0000003b01800000-0000003b01989b3b  /lib64/libc.so.6
0000003b01400000-0000003b0141fa0f  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
00007f59de1e9000-00007f59de4f10e3  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/jrockit/libjvm.so
00007f59ddfc7000-00007f59ddfe621b  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libjrosal.so
00007f59dddba000-00007f59dddc6553  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libjrutil.so
0000003b02400000-0000003b024826e7  /lib64/libm.so.6
0000003b02800000-0000003b0280687f  /lib64/librt.so.1
00007f59dd2ab000-00007f59dd2b6f73  /lib64/libnss_files.so.2
00007f59dd09b000-00007f59dd0a7483  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libjfr.so
00007f59dce7c000-00007f59dce88317  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
00007f59dcd4d000-00007f59dcd75283  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
0000003b05400000-0000003b05415ceb  /lib64/libnsl.so.1
00007f59dcbc2000-00007f59dcbc85bf  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
00007f59dc856000-00007f59dc863c03  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
00007f59dc397000-00007f59dc39c7e3  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
00007f59dc280000-00007f59dc292ca7  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
00007f597e2f2000-00007f597e2fbbbb  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libjmapi.so
00007f597e067000-00007f597e06cf9b  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/liborii.so
00007f597d54c000-00007f597d5529a3  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
00007f5959ba9000-00007f5959baa8dd  /opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/libweblogicunix1.so
00007f5958120000-00007f5958122014  /opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/libnodemanager.so
00007f5921110000-00007f5921112b87  /opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/libwlfileio3.so
00007f58f9720000-00007f58f97b2683  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/libawt.so
00007f58f961a000-00007f58f961e99f  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/headless/libmawt.so
00007f58eef7a000-00007f58eef7eb0b  /lib64/libnss_dns.so.2
0000003b03800000-0000003b03815a83  /lib64/libresolv.so.2
00007f58db83f000-00007f58db83f8bb  /opt/oracle/jrockit/jre/lib/amd64/librmi.so

Stack:
(* marks the word pointed to by the stack pointer)
00007f5959ae1b18: 00007f59815ad104* 00007f59de7ca5c0  00000000fedb9a20  0000000101862140  
00007f5959ae1b38: 0000000101862140  00000000fedb9a20  00007f59815ad0b0  0000000000000010  
00007f5959ae1b58: 00007f59815ad071  000000010b58ea50  00007f59815a5090  0000000101852798  
00007f5959ae1b78: 00000001018526c0  00000000fedb1810  00007f59db77aa10  00007f5959ae1d28  
00007f5959ae1b98: 00007f597e50f2c2  00007f5959ae1d28  00007f58dab2cd10  00007f5959ae1c30  
00007f5959ae1bb8: 000000010b58ea50  00007f58dab2cd10  00007f59d8b3c380  00007f5959ae1c30  

Code:
(* marks the word pointed to by the instruction pointer)
00007f58e3996ea0: 0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
00007f58e3996ec0: 0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
00007f58e3996ee0: 0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000155  
00007f58e3996f00: 00000000fedb6ed0* 00000000fedb9850  00000000fff81a98  00000000fedb1a30  
00007f58e3996f20: 00000000fedb9900  0000000000000000  00000000fedb3c10  00000000fedb3cc0  
00007f58e3996f40: 0000000000000000  00000000fedb3ed0  00000000fedb3f80  00000000fedb4030  


Last optimized methods:
  #1 jrockit/vm/RNI.callProfilerHelper(IJI)V  52.783-52.787 0x7f597f2dd000-0x7f597f2dd09c 3.32 ms 256KB  
  #2 weblogic/utils/classloaders/AbstractClassFinder.getClassSource(Ljava/lang/String;)Lweblogic/utils/classloaders/Source;  71.202-71.213 0x7f597f2dd0a0-0x7f597f2dd451 10.98 ms 768KB  
  #3 jrockit/vm/Allocator.allocObjectOrArray(JJIZ)Ljava/lang/Object;  73.219-73.225 0x7f597f2dd460-0x7f597f2dd5f0 5.66 ms 256KB  
  #4 weblogic/utils/io/FilenameEncoder.resolveRelativePath(Ljava/lang/String;CZ)Ljava/lang/String;  115.723-115.767 0x7f597f2dd600-0x7f597f2ddea0 43.77 ms 1024KB  
  #5 sun/nio/cs/UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/charset/CoderResult;  117.486-117.533 0x7f597f2ddea0-0x7f597f2dee10 47.23 ms 1536KB  
  #6 weblogic/utils/io/FilenameEncoder.resolveRelativeURIPath(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/String;  118.487-118.492 0x7f597f2dee20-0x7f597f2def25 4.45 ms 256KB  
  #7 jrockit/vm/ArrayCopy.memcpyBlock(Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;III)V  121.718-121.721 0x7f597f2def40-0x7f597f2df1a3 2.37 ms 256KB  
  #8 weblogic/utils/classloaders/ZipClassFinder.getSource(Ljava/lang/String;)Lweblogic/utils/classloaders/Source;  121.938-122.012 0x7f597f2df1c0-0x7f597f2dffbd 73.55 ms 1792KB  
  #9 jrockit/vm/Allocator.allocArray(JIZ)Ljava/lang/Object;  122.602-122.607 0x7f597f2dffc0-0x7f597f2e01c8 5.24 ms 256KB  
  #10 weblogic/utils/enumerations/SequencingEnumerator.hasMoreElements()Z  122.723-123.126 0x7f597f2e01e0-0x7f597f2e220c 402.71 ms 6400KB  
  #11 java/lang/String.charAt(I)C  123.126-123.127 0x7f597f2e2220-0x7f597f2e228e 0.87 ms 320KB  
  #12 jrockit/vm/ArrayCopy.copy(Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;II)V  123.284-123.310 0x7f597f2e22a0-0x7f597f2e2ed3 25.91 ms 1024KB  
 *#13 jrockit/vm/Allocator.allocObject(J)Ljava/lang/Object;  672.286-672.291 0x7f597f2e2ee0-0x7f597f2e3042 4.84 ms 256KB  

Thread:
"[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for" id=20 idx=0x54 tid=22430 lastJavaFrame=(nil)
Stack 0: start=0x7f5959aa1000, end=0x7f5959ae5000, guards=0x7f5959aa6000 (ok), forbidden=0x7f5959aa4000

Thread Stack Trace:
    at <unknown>(???.c)@0x7f58e3996f00
    at <unknown>(???.c)@0xfff813b8
    -- Java stack --
    at org/orbeon/private/apache/commons/codec/binary/BaseNCodec.r(BaseNCodec.java:40255)
    at org/orbeon/private/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:30)
    at org/orbeon/private/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.r(StringOps.scala:3244)
    at org/orbeon/oxf/portlet/OrbeonProxyPortlet.<init>(OrbeonProxyPortlet.scala:79)
    at jrockit/vm/RNI.c2java(JJJJJ)V(Native Method)
    -- end of trace

Memory usage report:
Total mapped                 16954688KB           (reserved=2977492KB)
-              Java heap     12582912KB           (reserved=0KB)
-              GC tables       420876KB          
-          Thread stacks        89524KB           (#threads=300)
-          Compiled code      1048576KB           (used=49107KB)
-               Internal         1864KB          
-                     OS       151044KB          
-                  Other      2290484KB          
-            Classblocks        19200KB           (malloced=18994KB #49480)
                                                  Not tracing sites.

-        Java class data       349184KB           (malloced=348970KB #226491 in 49480 classes)
                                                  Not tracing sites.

- Native memory tracking         1024KB           (malloced=329KB #10)
                                                  Not tracing sites.


Set the env variable TRACE_ALLOC_SITES=1 or use the print_memusage switch
trace_alloc_sites=true to enable alloc site tracing.

    **************************************************************************
    *  If you see this dump, please go to                                    *
    *  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/go2troubleshooting.html  *
    *  for troubleshooting information.                                      *
    **************************************************************************

===== END DUMP ===============================================================


/opt/oracle/weblogic12.1.1/middleware/user_projects/domains/test-staging/bin/startWebLogic.sh: line 180: 22399 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.policy ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}
<Apr 29, 2016 11:38:52 AM> <FINEST> <NodeManager> <Waiting for the process to die: 22347>
<Apr 29, 2016 11:38:52 AM> <INFO> <NodeManager> <Server failed so attempting to restart (restart count = 1)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms is not tested with JRockit. It is only tested with the standard Oracle HotSpot VM.

You could report this as a JRockit but to Oracle. But Oracle now recommends using the HotSpot VM. See this [Oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/migration_guide_from_jrockit_to). So I don't think reporting the JRockit but to Oracle would do much at this point.

In short the better way forward is not to use JRockit.